# Iterate over files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to iterate over a set of folders and copy them to a different location in PowerShell. All the folders follow the following naming convention:

```
20160621
```

This is obviously the day written in `yyyymmdd` format.  Since all of the folders follow this convention, my question is how would I say: copy all the folders from the past week"?  I have thought of using `(get-date).AddDays(-7)` but I am unsure how to recognize the folder names as date objects and not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [Get-ChildItem](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113308) cmdlet to retrieve the files and filter them using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet.

The following script combines three `Where`conditions

1. Get all directories
2. Ensure the directory name contains exactly six digits.
3. Parse the six digits to a `DateTime` object and ensure its earlier then seven days ago:

**Script:**

```
Get-ChildItem 'your_source' | Where-Object { 
    $_.PsIsContainer -and 
    $_.BaseName -match '\d{6}' -and 
    ([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.BaseName, 'yyyyMMdd', $null) -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)) 
} | Copy-Item -Destination 'Your_destination'
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Well almost..There are a few circumstances where folders with the same date exist in the destination.  How would I say "if exists merge contents"?

Comment: try `-force` on the Copy-Item cmdlet

Comment: would that merge the contents?

Comment: What you mean with `merge`?

Comment: Like not delete the current files but only add the new ones

Comment: It should do that, just give it a try.